# Logstash can not start > Pipelines YAML file is empty( use mac homebrew install)

Tags: macos, logstash, logstash-configuration

When I try start logstash server on my mac I get this error :

> Using bundled JDK: /usr/local/Cellar/logstash-full/7.12.0/libexec/jdk.app/Contents/Home
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
> Sending Logstash logs to /usr/local/Cellar/logstash-full/7.12.0/libexec/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
> [2021-04-05T15:11:47,502][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/local/Cellar/logstash-full/7.12.0/libexec/config/log4j2.properties
> [2021-04-05T15:11:47,521][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9 on 11.0.10+9 +indy +jit [darwin-x86_64]"}
> **`ERROR: Pipelines YAML file is empty. Location: /usr/local/Cellar/logstash-full/7.12.0/libexec/config/pipelines.yml`**
> usage:
> bin/logstash -f CONFIG_PATH [-t] [-r] [] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
> bin/logstash --modules MODULE_NAME [-M "MODULE_NAME.var.PLUGIN_TYPE.PLUGIN_NAME.VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE"] [-t] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
> bin/logstash -e CONFIG_STR [-t] [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace] [-w COUNT] [-l LOG]
> bin/logstash -i SHELL [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
> bin/logstash -V [--log.level fatal|error|warn|info|debug|trace]
> bin/logstash --help
> [2021-04-05T15:11:47,901][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
> org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
> at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
> at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
> at usr.local.Cellar.logstash_minus_full.$7_dot_12_dot_0.libexec.lib.bootstrap.environment.(/usr/local/Cellar/logstash-full/7.12.0/libexec/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]

after got this problem , I'm also try to add code

```
bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.test_and_exit
bin/logstash -f first-pipeline.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

and run logstash still the same problem , anyone can help? thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the file on the given location as explained here?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html

```
- pipeline.id: my-pipeline_1
  path.config: "/etc/path/to/p1.config"
  pipeline.workers: 3
- pipeline.id: my-other-pipeline
  path.config: "/etc/different/path/p2.cfg"
  queue.type: persisted
```